# Writing to a boolean inside a JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write to a local variable inside a JSONObjectRequest.  Here is my code:

```
JsonObjectRequest get_id_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ID, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                boolean load_full_data = false;
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonNotificationID = response.getJSONObject("n");


                    int notificationID = jsonNotificationID.getInt("id");

                    // Change flag to get full preferences below
                    if(notificationID > currentNotificationID) {
                        load_full_data = true;
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

I want to be able to check the server, if there are new IDs (different to the ones already stored in shared Preferences), then download the new ones.  So to do this, I want to set my variable `load_full_data = true`, then further down (oustide this request):

```
// Get the IDs, see if they are different.
volleyQueue.add(get_id_request);

if(load_full_data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "run: Load Full Data");
    volleyQueue.add(get_full_request);
}
```

Only thing is, I cant reference a local variable inside my JSONObjectRequest.  It says it needs to `final`.  How can I pass data in and out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new class and let it implement the interface whose definition you would like to enrich, in your case `Response.Listener<JSONObject>`
I am not familiar with this API but an example code would be like:

```
class MyResponseListener implements Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
      boolean isGoodParam;

      MyResponseListener(boolean isGoodParam) {
         this.isGoodParam = isGoodParam;
      }

      public isGoodParam() {
         return this.isGoodParam;
      }

       @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //use your param
            if(this.isGoodParam) {
                doStuff();
            }
       }
}
```

then your client code would be:

```
boolean initialIsGood = true;
MyResponseListener listener = new MyResponseListener(initialIsGood);
JsonObjectRequest getIdRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ID, null, listener,   
 Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        // TODO: Handle error
    });
//outside of the listener, assuming that the status of the boolean changed and you want to find out the new value
boolean newValue = listener.isGoodParam();
```

Cosmetic note: Please stick to the code convention standards, makes the code more readable. (for example camelCases and no_snakes :)

Comment: Thinking about it, how would this help me? I need to return the boolean outside of the listener, this still keeps it inside

Comment: I updated my answer, in this case it works just fine, but please do not adapt adding getters in your classes if you can avoid it. Please let me know if your question is acceptable :)

Comment: Okay,  I will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: I am getting an error on the like new new `JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ID, null, listener);`, I dont think its getting the correct params in the right order or something.

Comment: Okay, as I said I am not familiar with the API. It seems (according to the documentation) that the  Response.ErrorListener is missing, so you could add it. It is also always helpful, that one also posts details about the error.

Comment: It seems the function has changed, it is now `new JsonObjectRequest(URL_ID, jsonObject, apiResponseListener, new Response.ErrorListener(){});`  Although i'm not sure what the jsonObject is going to be, maybe the response?

Comment: Okay I found the docs (at last), and the jsonObject is the params to pass.  With this constructor, it defaults to GET.  So I can pass null for the jsonObject.  Thanks, I learnt a lot.

Comment: https://afzaln.com/volley/index.html?com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html